Android Studio Koala Feature Drop: Project explorer automatically closed when android studio loses focus and receive again
I have Mackbook pro (M3 Pro chipset). I have downloaded the latest Android Studio Koala Feature Drop IDE. And imported my existing project (project was created from Windows).
Project successfully imported, and I can also open the files and run into the Emulators.
But when, Android Studio loses the focus and received focus again, then project explorer and all the open files automatically closed.
E.g: While working on Android Studio, I goes to Browser or any other application. And when I back to android studio all my open files closed.
I have to double click on the project name, and open all the files again. But after opening file, I can't undo the changes, where I was just working few seconds back.
But the new project created from the macbook, working fine.
I have also tried the Ladybug and Jellyfish android studio versions. But issue is same.
Can anyone please help to understand / fix this issue??

